# Can we 'predict' the delta of a stock? The delta of a stock is $\pm 1$ right?

Tags: equities, greeks, delta-hedging, delta

**Re the off-topic:** 'Basic financial questions are off-topic as they are assumed to be common knowledge for those studying or working in the field of quantitative finance' --> I don't think this is a basic financial question because it involves mathematical concept of derivative.

---

> A stock is like a living organism. A sparrow, say. And we are able to create an emergent-based abstraction of that sparrow, which closely approximates the sparrow itself, accounting for migration patterns, wind, weather, and other variables. We can create a similar abstraction of a stock combining the information from the specific ETFs, which represent its underlying dependencies. And if we apply this to the stock we can predict its delta, following the path of its extracted self, because nature follows abstraction.

- Taylor Mason, [Billions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Billions_(TV_series)) S02E10

Delta of $V$ is $$\frac{\partial V}{\partial S}$$

So delta of S (long) or -S (short) is $$\frac{\partial (\pm S)}{\partial S} = \pm 1 \ ?$$

If so, does this mean the [hypothesis is unnecessary](http://abstrusegoose.com/353)?

> if we apply this to the stock

because anyone, for any stock,

> can predict its delta

?

I have a feeling the show might've been just saying a bunch of words to sound smart but then turned out incorrect.

Comment: I want to recommend Interest Rate Models - Theory and Practice book by Damiano Brigo and Fabio Mercurio to you, just becasue your affinity to quotes. :)

Comment: Sometimes the math gets in the way of the poetry and vice versa...

Comment: @vanguard2k stocal prof already gave us handout from there. Hilarious. Even privault quoted wolf of wall Street

Comment: Honestly that quote does not seem very meaningful, looks to me as a copy of the brilliant "The World is a Corporation" scene from _Network_ (1976): https://youtu.be/35DSdw7dHjs

Comment: @DaneelOlivaw thanks for sharing!

Comment: @vanguard2k please vote to reopen or upvote

Comment: @noob2 please vote to reopen or upvote

Comment: @noob2 so what's the poetry meant? is the quote meaningful if taylor said option or something instead of delta

Comment: @noob2 actually is the quote possibly meaningful if taylor said option or something instead of delta?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

By definition of delta, yes:

$$ f(S)=\pm 1 \times S \quad \Rightarrow \quad \frac{\partial f}{\partial S}(S) = \pm 1$$

Comment: Daneel Olivaw, thanks. Does this mean the hypothesis is unnecessary?

Comment: I guess, I am not sure what hypothesis you are referring to @BCLC. That quote does not make much sense anyway.

Comment: thanks Daneel Olivaw! btw, do you agree with 'the show might've been just saying a bunch of words to sound smart but then turned out incorrect' ?

Comment: @BCLC I can always "interpret" the quote, but I doubt the original intent was so. But in any case, the delta of the stock is always 1, no need to predict. "[...] _because nature follows abstraction_" well you have people that argue modern derivative pricing models have predated trading in those same products, and the framework underpinning these models ("_abstraction_") has ended up shaping the practical trading of them ("_nature_" or real life), see for example the book _An Engine, Not a Camera: How Financial Models Shape Markets_ by MacKenzie.